# Parameter error SQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to create a wildcard search query on my website but whenever I try to test out the search query with anything it gives me the following parameter error.

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /srv/disk11/2450097/www/luke.dx.am/Search.php on line 33
```

Here is the query I am trying to execute.

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT products. *, Category. *, Colour. *, Description. *, Designers. *, Image. *, Item. *, Sexs. *, Sizes. *
                            From products
                            INNER JOIN Category
                            On products.CatagoryCode = Category.CatagoryCode
                            INNER JOIN Colour
                            on products.ColourCode = Colour.ColourCode
                            INNER JOIN Description
                            ON products.DescriptionCode = Description.DescriptionCode
                            INNER JOIN Designers
                            ON products.DesignerCode = Designers.DesignerCode
                            INNER JOIN Image
                            on products.ImageCode = Image.ImageCode
                            INNER JOIN Item
                            ON products.ItemCode = Item.ItemCode
                            INNER JOIN Sexs
                            ON products.SexCode = Sexs.SexCode
                            INNER JOIN Sizes
                            ON products.SizeCode = Sizes.SizeCode
                            WHERE Category. * LIKE '%searchq%' 
                            OR Colour. * LIKE '%searchq%'
                            OR Description. * LIKE '%searchq%'
                            OR Designers. * LIKE '%searchq%'
                            OR Image. * LIKE '%searchq%'
                            OR Item. * LIKE '%searchq%'
                            OR products. * LIKE '%searchq%'
                            OR Sexs. * LIKE '%searchq%'
                            OR Sizes. * LIKE '%searchq%'")
                            or die("Search could not be completed.");
```

If it helps the web address is luke.dx.am and the page which the search should be directed to is luke.dx.am/Search.php.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass two parameters in mysqli_query. The first is the connection to be execute the query and the second is the query.

```
...

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM my_table");
```

Comment: That seems to have done something but now I get another error.                                 
'Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /srv/disk11/2450097/www/luke.dx.am/Search.php on line 83
Search could not be completed.'                                                                                        See luke.dx.am/Stock.php for updated code.

Comment: Oh yes... the expression “Foo.* LIKE “ is wrong. You need write the column name to do you use the operator LIKE.